# C# Aggregate function definition explanation

Tags: c#

There are 3 overload versions of Enumerable.Aggregate. I couldn't find any overload version of this function to match the one used in [official example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
public static TSource Aggregate<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TSource, TSource> func
)
```

The above definition is totally different from this official example:

```
string sentence = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

// Split the string into individual words.
string[] words = sentence.Split(' ');

// Prepend each word to the beginning of the 
// new sentence to reverse the word order.
string reversed = words.Aggregate((workingSentence, next) =>
                                      next + " " + workingSentence);

Console.WriteLine(reversed);

// This code produces the following output:
//
// dog lazy the over jumps fox brown quick the
```

Here are 3 overload versions of Aggregate function:

```
public static TSource Aggregate<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TSource, TSource> func);

public static TAccumulate Aggregate<TSource, TAccumulate>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, TAccumulate seed, Func<TAccumulate, TSource, TAccumulate> func);

public static TResult Aggregate<TSource, TAccumulate, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, TAccumulate seed, Func<TAccumulate, TSource, TAccumulate> func, Func<TAccumulate, TResult> resultSelector);
```

None of them match the function used in the above example. Is the official document wrong? or I missed sth? Please help me bridge the gap between 3 versions of function definition and this official example.

How to understand the function definition?

Comment: Actually first overload you mention **is** the same as used in that "official example".

Comment: Review [Extension Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static TSource Aggregate<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TSource, TSource> func
)
```

This is actually the one used in the official example:

```
string reversed = words.Aggregate((workingSentence, next) =>
                                      next + " " + workingSentence);
```

Some pieces that might be confusing you are:

1. the `this` keyword in front of the `source` parameter identifies it as an Extension method, which means the above code is syntax sugar for:

   ```
   string reversed = Enumerable.Aggregate(words, (workingSentence, next) =>
                                     next + " " + workingSentence);
   ```
2. `TSource` is a generic parameter, which in this case is substituted with `string` because the compiler is able to *infer* this type from the fact that `words` is an `IEnumerable<string>`.
3. `Func<TSource, TSource, TSource>` is a generic delegate representing a function that takes two parameters (the first two `TSource`s), and returns a `TSource`. This is in contrast to `Action<TSource, TSource>`, which would take two parameters and not return a value. Either of these types can be represented with a lambda expression with the form `(param1, param2) => expression`.

Comment: Func<TSource, TSource, TSource> func is function takes 3 parameters? or the first 2 are 2 param types, the 3rd type is return type?

Answer (score 2):

The example you gave uses the first overload you posted. It might be because it's an extension method that is throwing you off.

With an extension method, the `this` parameter becomes a reference to the instance that it is called on. When the code is compiled, it is translated into the proper static method call. Basically, when you write this:

```
words.Aggregate((workingSentence, next) =>
                                  next + " " + workingSentence);
```

It compiles into this:

```
Enumerable.Aggregate<string>(words, (workingSentence, next) =>
                                  next + " " + workingSentence);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `this` modifier indicates that the overload is an [Extension Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx).

So in this case, `this IEnumerable<TSource> source` in the method definition corresponds to `words` in the example.

Answer (score 1):

The official document is completely correct. In the official example the following signature is used:

```
public static TSource Aggregate<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TSource, TSource> func);
```

It is an extension method then string[] word as an array of string matches IEnumerable source. And the following code is match with Func func:

```
(workingSentence, next) => next + " " + workingSentence
```

In other words you can write:

```
Func<string, string, string> func = (workingSentence, next) => next + " " + workingSentence;
words.Aggregate(func);
```

Two first strings in func are input and the last one is the return value type that in this example is aggregation of two strings.