# C# Aggregate function definition Overload #1 explanation

Tags: c#

Someone can explain the diferents sections of Aggregate functions' overloads?

[image: Image Aggregate's overloads]

@StriplingWarrior made a very good explication of a similar question [C# Aggregate function definition explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43194098/c-sharp-aggregate-function-definition-explanation) someone can do the same with others Aggregate function definition Overload ?

1. What is the meaning of TResult,  what type a TResult is?
2. What is the menaing of Aggregate<TSource, TAccumulate, TResult>, What is the diference between Aggregate<TSource, TAccumulate, TResult> and Aggregate<TSource, TAccumulate> and Aggregate<TSource, TAccumulate>
3. What is the meaning of TAccumulate, what type a TAccumulate is?
4. What is the diference between Func<TAccumulate, TResult> and Func<TAccumulate, TSource, TAccumulate> and Func<TSource, TSource, TSource>

Comment: This is wayyy too broad. However, start here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics

Answer (score 1):

Consider we have a `byte` array and the last `byte` is parity that it is `xor` of all other bytes.
if we want to check the parity using `Aggregate` we can do something like this:

```
public bool IsCorrect
{
    get => Telegram.Aggregate(0, (result, item) => result ^ item, result => result == 0);
}
```

In this case `TResult` is `bool`, because I want to return a `bool` value and `TSource` is byte because `Telegram` is array of bytes and `TAccumulate` is `int` because the result of `xor` of bytes is `int`. in this case `seed` is 0 because for the first `byte` it should do `xor` with something.

We can also add a parity to the end of array:

```
Telegram.Add(Telegram.Aggregate((result, item) => (byte)(result ^ item)));
```

In this example I've used the third. `Telegram` is a byte array and I want to return a `byte` and in each step the result of `xor` would be `byte`.